# Taking an array of Objects and filtering each objects keys by an array of string

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am pulling backend data to my application, but i want the user to be able to select which keys they want to see. So i have been trying to build a way for them to generate an array of strings and have that be compared to each object in the array and output the new array of objects with each key excluded.

Here is the Filter array:

```js
const filterData = 
[
'TestOne',
'TestTwo',
]
```

Here is the array of objects:

```js
const data = [
  {
    _id: "62ec2f1084c7f48175a9cb4a",
    Date: "2022-08-04T15:41:37.567Z",
    facilityId: "62e5a9fd45f2646fc7361fa3",
    userId: "62e16d390f4685e4fdb6a288",
    formData: {
      Date: "2022-08-04T15:41:37.567Z",
      TestOne: 60002,
      TestTwo: 19998,
      TestThree: 102,
      TestFour: "True"
    },
  },
  {
    _id: "62ec2f1c84c7f48175a9cb58",
    Date: "2022-08-04T15:41:52.932Z",
    facilityId: "62e5a9fd45f2646fc7361fa3",
    userId: "62e16d390f4685e4fdb6a288",
    formData: {
      Date: "2022-08-04T15:41:52.932Z",
      TestOne: 60003,
      TestTwo: 19997,
      TestThree: 103,
      TestFour: "True"
    },
  },
]
```

I want to build a function that takes the `data.formData` and filters out any keys that are not included in the `filterData`. I am having a hard time figuring out what exactly needs done to acheive this. If anyone could help id greatly appreciate it.

----**EDIT**----
Here is something of a process that i have thought of but it returns errors and cant really think of why.

```js
  const formObject =
    datas.length > 0 &&
    datas.map((data, i) => {
      const filterData = ['TestOne', 'TestTwo']
      filterData.map((filter) => {
        delete data.formData[filter]
      })
    })
```

This function gives me errors of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot delete property 'TestThree' of #<Object>`, ive tried making a new instance of datas but it doesnt work

Comment: Post the JavaScript that's giving you problems and we'll fix it for you.

Comment: @zer00ne im not 100% on how to go about achieving what i want is the issue. I have figured id map through each data object and somehow filter each `formData` key that doesnt match with the filterData. But im not 100% on how to do it.

Comment: Put something up, it's expected that the **OP** **O**riginal **P**oster (aka you), show that you've tried to do something with actual code, otherwise it comes off as if you're just asking someone to write code for you which is something we are supposed to avoid. See [ask] and also how to post a [mcve]

Comment: @zer00ne i have added a function that i have tried making work but it just give errors.

Comment: That's expected, just add any comments concerning the error and what you think might be wrong. It's kind of like when you bring your car to the mechanic (unless you are a mechanic) and you try to explain what's wrong . The mechanic would eventually figure out what's wrong but would save time if told what was wrong upfront.

Comment: @zer00ne i have since updated the function and provided the error code i get from it

Comment: Sounds like the object is frozen, I modified my answer to clone a copy since that's the only way you can get results from a frozen object is by working on a copy.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```js
const result = data.map(x => {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(x.formData)) {
        if (!filterData.includes(key)) {
            delete x.formData[key];
        }
    }
    return x;
})
```

Hope this helps

Comment: i get this error `Cannot delete property 'TestThree' of #<Object>`

Comment: what node version do you use? it works on my laptop (node v16.14.1)

Comment: im using a react enviorment for this. The datas is in state level but even if i iterate over the array with  `const newData = [...data]` it still doesnt work.

Comment: can you share the complete react component?

Comment: there is not much inside of it apart from the state controllers with redux and the function itself

Comment: i know it has to deal with the immutability of the state level `data` variable. i just cant figure out how to iterate over it and use it inside that function

Answer (score 0):

The key highlights to this function are:

- Before the first loop, the array is cloned<sup>✥</sup> then each object is skimmed over to find `"formData"`. Since the actual keys are known, I'm going on the logical assumption that the object that has them is known as well -- hence the second parameter `path`.

  `Object.keys(obj['formData'])` = `["Date", "TestOne", "TestTwo", "TestThree", "TestFour"]` :

  **Figure I**

  ```js
  function filterData(array, path, ...keys) {
     let clone = structuredClone(array);
     for (let obj of clone) {

       Object.keys(obj[path]).flatMap(key =>
             //... obj[path] = [ {{["formData"]}}...
               //... ["Date", "TestOne", "TestTwo", "TestThree", "TestFour"]
  ```
- On the second loop, the keys form the first loop is checked vs. the third parameter `...keys`, a rest parameter that consists of one or more keys to filter out. The if condition has been reversed with `!` operator:

  **Figure II**

  ```js
  if (![...keys].includes(key)) {
    return [];
  }
  return delete obj[path][key];
  ```

<sup><sup>✥</sup>The `TypeError` sounds like the object is frozen so by cloning the array you can freely work on the clone.</sup>

```js
const data = [{
  _id: "62ec2f1084c7f48175a9cb4a",
  Date: "2022-08-04T15:41:37.567Z",
  facilityId: "62e5a9fd45f2646fc7361fa3",
  userId: "62e16d390f4685e4fdb6a288",
  formData: {
    Date: "2022-08-04T15:41:37.567Z",
    TestOne: 60002,
    TestTwo: 19998,
    TestThree: 102,
    TestFour: "True"
  }
}, {
  _id: "62ec2f1c84c7f48175a9cb58",
  Date: "2022-08-04T15:41:52.932Z",
  facilityId: "62e5a9fd45f2646fc7361fa3",
  userId: "62e16d390f4685e4fdb6a288",
  formData: {
    Date: "2022-08-04T15:41:52.932Z",
    TestOne: 60003,
    TestTwo: 19997,
    TestThree: 103,
    TestFour: "True"
  }
}];


/**
 * Find any given number of keys and remove them
 * @param {array<object>} array - An array of objects
 * @param {string} path - Name of the key if the target object is one
 *        level down. (todo: recursive algorithm to dig deeper)
 * @param {string/array<string>} keys - List of keys to filter out
 * @return {array<object>} The array sans filtered keys
 */
function filterData(array, path, ...keys) {
  let clone = structuredClone(array);
  for (let obj of clone) {
    Object.keys(obj[path]).flatMap(key => {
      if (![...keys].includes(key)) {
        return [];
      }
      return delete obj[path][key];
    });
  }
  return clone;
}

let x = filterData(data, "formData", "Date", "TestFour");

console.log(x);
```